# Thread fails if the latency time goes above 60 seconds in Jmeter, i cannot test further

Tags: jmeter

Hi i am using jmeter for performance test of my Rest api's, i am stuck with the latency time, if the latency time goes above 60 seconds, then the thread fails..

Threads  - 100 
Rampup - 1 sec
Loop - 10

[image]

check out the image, for all my request i cannot proceed further beyond 60 seconds, it shows 504 bad gateway error. 
How to increase the response time of each request. is there any settings to run my test successfully after 60 seconds without any failure
(Note:- Backend server is running till the request completing)

Answer (score -1):

You can setup timeout directly in HTTP Request sampler

[image]

Or you can config values `httpclient.timeout` (default=0) in jmeter.properties file or try to change `http.socket.timeout$Integer` in hc.parameters. Both files could be find in Jmeter's bin/ directory.